# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error message. Why do I get this message?

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I'm confused by this error message, and I am not sure how to debug. I looked at similar questions, and I think I found the part in the code that needs to be fixed, but I am unsure on how to go about it.

Here is the code -

```
app.post('/sign_up_results', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.administrator === 'on') {
        data = {name : req.body.name, password: req.body.password, user: 'administrator'};
        pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data, function(err, result) {
        // If I omit this if statement it works fine
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
        });  
        res.render('review_papers');
    } else if (req.body.user === 'on') {
        data = {name : req.body.name, password: req.body.password, user: 'user'};
        pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data, function(err, result) {
        // If I omit this if statement it works fine
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
        });  
        res.render('upload_paper');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be extra careful with callback function `pool.query`. In the old codes,

```
data = {
  name: req.body.name,
  password: req.body.password,
  user: 'administrator'
};
pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data, function (err, result) {
  // If I omit this if statement it works fine
  if (err) {
    next(err);
    return;
  }
});
res.render('review_papers');
```

`res.render` will be executed first than `pool.query`. So, basically you already tell that request is done without waiting `pool.query` to finish.

A few seconds later, `pool.query` is finished. Your issue is because your query encountered an error so it will go to `next(err)` which is also tell that your request is done. This is invalid because you can't tell request is done more than one time. It causes `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error message`.

The simple workaround is to move `res.render` inside the `pool.query` such as

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data, function (err, result) {
  // If I omit this if statement it works fine
  if (err) {        
    return next(err); // we can just return here
  }

  res.render('review_papers');
});
```